# Populating the Rest of a Row/Avoiding Violation of Null Constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (called new_table). It consists of 4 fields. id (with PK and NOT NULL) and field1, field2, and field3 (which have do not have NOT NULL).
The only data populated in the table are the 1 and 2 in the id field. (I'll include a screenshot below) Now I want to populate the rest of those two rows with some values by using the query below.

```
INSERT INTO new_table (field1, field2, field3)
VALUES
 ('value1', 'value2', 'value3'),
 ('value4', 'value5', 'value6');
```

And here is what I always get:

> "ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, value1, value2, value3)."

Is it thinking that I'm trying to populate the third and fourth rows? How do I just populate the rest of rows 1 and 2 with those values?

[table currently looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwvM8.png)

Comment: You are probably assuming that `id` is a serial type (an integer column with a generator-supplied DEFAULT value)

Comment: joop it's just regular integer with a PK and not null. No serial

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: Well, then you'll have to provide a value for it when inserting a record.

Comment: joop I'm not trying to insert any more records. I'm trying to complete the record with an id=1 and id=2. So I need to use an update. Right? I'll include a screenshot of it up above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting new rows as you suspected (notionally lets consider them row 3/4) and not updating rows 1 and 2. To update the existing rows, use an update statement.

```
UPDATE new_table 
SET
    field1= 'value1'
    , field2='value2'
    , field3='value3' 
WHERE id = 1;

UPDATE new_table 
SET
    field1= 'value4'
    , field2='value5'
    , field3='value6' 
WHERE id = 2;
```

Comment: The data type of ID, I assumed to be numeric (since nothing else was specified and that would be normal) but you may have an ID which is a varchar, in which case it would need an Id = '1' - if it is character, but you intend to store numeric IDs, change the data type to a suitable numeric.

Comment: The id data type is integer

Comment: Depending on what your settings are in terms of what tool you are using, you may need to commit; the change. The change should be visible to the tool you used to perform the update though.

Comment: Slightly confused by your self answer saying to put the where clause in, there is a where clause in the answer. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why your code is all the sudden working for me. There must have been some sort of bug. Essentially what was happening was, the query was deleting all the data in my table (which was just the data in those id fields at that point). Long story short, I restarted and your code works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You would do this in an `update`, and you can phrase this kind-of-similarly to the `insert`:

```
update new_table t
    set field1 = v.field1,
        field2 = v.field2,
        field3 = v.field3
    from ( (<id1>, 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'),
           (<id2>, 'value4', 'value5', 'value6')
         ) v(id, field1, field2, field3)
    where t.id = v.id;
```

`<id1>` and `<id2>` are however you define the match to the "first two rows".